# Geany not running python code

Tags: python, geany

I'm working with a code in python. Today I moved from the text editor Kate to Geany because some people recommended me to do this. This morning I was running from Geany without any problem, now I run the same code and get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bmag2.py", line 6, in <module>
      from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
ImportError: No module named scipy.optimize
```

If I run the file "bmag2.py" from the terminal, everything is ok.

Do you know what could be happening? How can I fix this?

Comment: Python code isn't compiled, it's interpreted.

Comment: Maybe your PATH changed and the library `scipy` is no longer available?

Comment: @wallyk where can I check that? (I didn't do anything manual)

Comment: If you are on Linux or Unix, type `which python` (or `which python3` or whatever you use to run python), then look in nearby directories for python-3.2.3/lib (for example) for `scipy.py` or `scipy.pyc` etc.  For example, if `which` says `/usr/local/bin/python` look in `/usr/local/python-3`-something.

Comment: You can check this also easy by starting a an interactive python shell e.g. from inside a termnal and import the modul over there